# regrading erase function for sequence containers

Tags: c++, stl

Below text is snippet of Effective STL Item 9

```
ofstream logFile; // log file to write to
AssocContainer<int> c;
…
for (AssocContainer<int>::iterator i = c.begin(); // loop conditions are the
     i !=c.end();){ //same as before
     if (badValue(*i)){
         logFile << "Erasing " << *i <<'\n'; // write log file
         c.erase(i++); // erase element
      }
      else ++i;
}
```

It's vector, string, and deque that now give us trouble. We can't use the erase-remove idiom any longer, because there's no way to get erase or remove to write the log file. Furthermore, we can't use the loop we just developed for associative containers, because it yields undefined behavior for vectors, strings, and deques! Recall that for such containers, invoking erase not only invalidates all iterators pointing to the erased element, it also invalidates all iterators beyond the erased element. In our case, that includes all iterators beyond i. It doesn't matter if we write i++, ++I, or anything else you can think of, because none of the resulting iterators is valid.

We must take a different tack with vector, string, and deque. In particular, we must take advantage of erase's return value. That return value is exactly what we need: it's a valid iterator pointing to the element following the erased element once the erase has been accomplished. In other words, we write this:

```
for (SeqContainer<int>::iterator i = c.beqin();
       i != c.end();){
       if (badValue(*i)){
          logFile << "Erasing " << *i << '\n';
          i = c.erase(i); // keep i valid by assigning
       } //erase's return value to it
       else ++i;
}
```

My question is author mentions that if we use erase on vectors, strings, deques "invalidates all iterators pointing to the erased element, it also invalidates all iterators beyond the erased element", but later statement is contradicting if we use return value of erase then we can use it, Question: **"Isn't erase invalidate all pointer beyond erased element?**

Comment: You should indent your code.

Comment: What would be the point for `erase()` to return an already invalidated iterator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question: "Isn't erase invalidate all pointer beyond erased element?

It may, but it is irrelevant to you in this case. `erase()` may invalidate existing iterators which obtained before this call to `erase()`, but what `erase()` itself returns is a new, valid iterator in any case.

Comment: is following iterators are also valid? Is erase make sure we get following iterators are also valid?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "following iterators" and when you got them. If you obtain them before call of `erase()` they could be invalidated (depends on container), if after then of course they are valid.

Comment: @ Slava i am looking for after erase, as you mentioned it is valid. Now it is clear. Thanks for the help